# Why kendo time picker set to 12:00AM when dateInput property is set to true?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I'm confused why `kendo ui` date time picker value changes to `12:00 AM` when I explicitly select a value (not `12:00 AM`) from the list.

The behavior of the widget has been observed when `dateInput` property is explicitly set to `true`. However, remove `dateInput` property or set to `false` will make the widget behave normally.

I have put up a `dojo` to mimic the behavior. https://dojo.telerik.com/IMofaPob/2

Could be `bug`? or I just didn't understand how to use `dateInput` property correcty?

Any inputs is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are setting the value new a new Date() object that has no time information in the constructor.  That's why it is set to a time of midnight. [Fixed example](https://dojo.telerik.com/IMofaPob/3)

Comment: @DrewB. In the dojo code example, I explicitly put these lines of code `var timepicker = $("#timepicker").data("kendoTimePicker");
timepicker.value(new Date(2016, 10, 1));
timepicker.trigger("change");` on purpose.  If you see in the `kendoTimePicker` constructor, `dateInput` property is set to true.  If that is the case, when you get an instance of the time picker, and set the value to a new `Date` and trigger `change` event.  And, when you change time picker widget to any value, after the widget loses its focus, the value will reset to `12:00 AM`, it doesn't persist the selected value.

Comment: But if you set widget `dateInput` to false, then change `timepicker` to any value, the selected value will persist in the control, it does not reset to `12:00 AM`.  Why does setting `dateInput` to true makes the widget behaves dodgy?